# How do i make a list with x1,y1,x2,y2,x3,y3.... into (x1,y1), (x2,y2), (x3,y3)

Tags: arrays, list

the two input list are coordinates x and y. They are input separately, and I am trying to combine the two input into xy coordinates in array form.

I am trying to make two list into an array

for example here is the two individual list:
x = [x1,x2,x3,x4]
y = [y1,y2,y3,y4]

then I combine the input into one list:

xy=[x for y in(x, y) for x in y]

where it is arrange in [x1,y1,x2,y2,x3,y3,x4,y4]

however I'm stuck in the next step which is making it into an array that has this order

array_xy = ((x1,y1),(x2,y2),(x3,y3),(x4,y4))

Any idea how can I make the xy list into the array_xy?

Comment: Hi, are you sure after xy=[x for y in(x, y) for x in y], it  is arrange in [x1,y1,x2,y2,x3,y3,x4,y4]? It seems like [x1,x2,x3,x4,y1,y2,y3,y4] instead.

Comment: yea im wrong on that part...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can make it directly from `x` and `y` with `zip`:

```
list(zip(x, y))
```

I hope I understand what you want correctly.

By the way, I think `xy` is `[x1, x2, x3, x4, y1, y2, y3, y4]` how you wrote it.

But you can construct what you want from it like this:

```
array_xy = [(xy[i], xy[i+len(x)]) for i in range(len(x))]
```